# Swift: Is there a way to let only certain subclasses have access to an extension of the superclass

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, interface-builder, xib

I am currently at the start of a project and trying to make some universal inspectable/designable variables for UIViews, UIButtons, and UIImageViews to make designing in InterfaceBuilder easier. For example:

```
@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}
```

One suggestion I've seen to accomplish this is:

```
extension UIView { 

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

However, the problem with this is that now *all* subclasses of UIView, show the inspectable properties, which is problematic when I will only be using these properties on maybe three classes, and I add more properties like border width/color, shadow radius, opacity, offset, and color, and these take up a lot of the inspector pane in IB.

I'd like something like this:

```
@IBDesignable class MyView: UIView, MyDesignable {}
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton, MyDesignable {}
@IBDesignable class MyImageView: UIImageView, MyDesignable {}

protocol MyDesignable {}

extension MyDesignable where Self: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    ...
```

Unfortunately, `@IBInspectable` springs the error `Only instance properties can be declared @IBInspectable`.

I also tried:

```
@IBDesignable class MyView: UIView {}
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton {}
@IBDesignable class MyImageView: UIImageView {}

private extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

However, other UIView subclasses still showed the inspectable properties.

Hopefully the question and intent behind it make sense. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you!